# PyCharm cannot use interpreter in server docker-machine(Channel disconnected before any data was reveived)

Tags: docker, pycharm

I am using MAC OS + PyCharm(for pro) and ubuntu16.04 server.

When I try to connect to the server's docker using local pycharm, I get the following error:

[image]

**( Cannot connect: java.io.IOException: Channel disconnected before any data was reveived )**

( I changed the docker daemon port. )

And, I tried searching for ports, and worked well.

```
Port Scanning host: 163.---.---.178 
Open TCP Port:  7561
```

Even if I tried changing tcp to https, it gave an error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try providing certificates folder? `docker-machine env ...` should output the path. Btw PyCharm doesn't natively support remote docker, not sure if it will work through the docker-machine. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489

Answer (score -2):

1.set this item first, then reboot your laptop. Run pycharm as administrator, it works for me.